# run.bat will not properly open the command prompt

Tags: java

I'm trying to use a `.bat` file to run a `Shimeji`, but when I double-click the file it opens the command prompt for half a second then closes automatically. I've been looking all over for a proper answer to this but can't find one I really understand.
Try to give it to me in simple terms because I've never done something like this before

contents: java -jar Shimeji-ee.jar

Comment: When you run a script file from Windows Explorer, it provides a shell for the duration of the program. If you want it to last longer, run the `.bat` from the command line. There are kludges, such as throwing a `pause` command at the end of the `.bat`, but that's only going to frustrate folks who actually *do* use a command line.

Comment: Have you tried to read how to set it up throught their web site?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo i tried running it directly from the command prompt but it just says "unable to access jarfile shimeji-ee.jar"